# Is it posible to split the respons from http_poller to several docments in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-configuration

I use logstash http_poller plugin to get audit data from a database and pushes the data to elasticsearch. The response contains an array of elements
is it posible to split the poller response into several dokuments in elasticsearch ?

This is the http_poller response :

```
{
    response:[
    {
        "start_timestamp": "2019-04-28T22:14:34.746Z",
        "duration_ms": 566,
        "user_name": "anonymous",
        "sql_text": "****",
        "resource_path": "/services/webservices/HR/**"
    },

    {
        "start_timestamp": "2019-04-28T22:14:39.516Z",
        "duration_ms": 200,
        "user_name": "anonymous",
        "sql_text": "***",
        "resource_path": "/services/webservices/HR/***"
    }
    ]
}
```

I need to be able to split the response array into several elastic documents. One document for each array element.

I have tried to use a splitter, but it does not seem to solve my issue

Comment: this thread might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41746502/serilog-http-sink-logstash-splitting-serilog-message-array-into-individual-lo/41756350#41756350

Comment: Thanks! looks like the problem is similar.